# Open spicific ViewController via push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I've got some troubles with triggering push notifications. I need to open specific VC when user taps on notification which has some payload for it. Considering case that app is background I'm using this code

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

        if ((application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background)) {

            //open specific VC depends on notification payload
        }
    }
```

Here the problems starts: 1) I cant push VC from AppDelegate, only by setting new rootController 2) I have to use this code from AppDelegate's didReceiveRemoteNotification method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to this answer: [How to make your push notification Open a certain view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753063/how-to-make-your-push-notification-open-a-certain-view-controller)

Use this code in AppDelegate to detect if the app is opened from the notification. Before the app has become active, Set the initial VC when the app state is **UIApplicationStateInactive**. Write your code to set your VC as well as the content within that VC.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

    if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

        //app is currently active, can update badges count here

    } else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

        //app is in background, if content-available key of your notification is set to 1, poll to your backend to retrieve data and update your interface here

    } else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

        //app is transitioning from background to foreground (user taps notification), do what you need when user taps here

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        UIViewController *viewController = // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];

        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    }

}
```

Comment: @sedq You may accept the answer if it was a help. It will help others.