# How to Show a Certain View Controller and Send the Data After We Tap the Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to read similar thread in here [How to make your push notification Open a certain view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753063/how-to-make-your-push-notification-open-a-certain-view-controller) 
but the information is not complete.

I am trying to implement push notification (`firebase cloud messaging`). after receiving the notification alert, i want if the user tap that notification, it will send the user to a certain view controller and open the data that have been sent from the server.

> 1. how to access the data/information from the server that has been sent through push notification?
> 2. send that data/information to a certain view controller?

Here is my code in app delegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var fcmTokenUser : String?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()


        print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last! as String)


        // To get FCM token that will be sent to APNS via Google FCM
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        fcmTokenUser = token




        return true
    }



    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String){
         // This callback is fired at each app startup (when the user install the app for the very first time) and whenever a new token is generated due to The app is restored on a new device, The user uninstalls/reinstall the app, The user clears app data.

        // after fcm generated for the very first time,then fcm can also be retrieved in the 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method above (let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken)


        fcmTokenUser = fcmToken





    }




    private func application(application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    }





}
```

Comment: Did you try this solution?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706455/open-app-in-specific-view-when-user-taps-on-push-notification-with-ios-swift

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `AppDelegate` to detect the user `tap` (response) and after double tap it will show you a certain `viewController` as you specified.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        //THIS PRINT WILL SHOW YOU THE USER TAP ON NOTIFICATION    
        print("userNotificationCenter --- \(response) --- ")

        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let otherVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourViewControllerIdentifier") as! yourViewControllerClassName
        window?.rootViewController = otherVC;  
    }
```

To access the `data/information` from the server that has been sent through `push notification` -

The notification data is delivered to your app in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`. If you want to process it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` you should store it in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and read it again in `applicationDidBecomeActive.`

Answer (score 0):

the delegate method to
 Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {

    //get required values from data
    completionHandler();
//push to view controller

}
```

Note: Save this dictionary data in model after parse or save the dictionary object on project level to use in any where in the project.
Than before push to any view controller declare dictionary or modal that controller in which way you want to see the date there.